# Making the jfeinstein Sliding Menu wrap content

Tags: android, dpi, slidingmenu

I understand that to display the sliding menu you must use menu.setBehindWidth(380); to toggle how much you want the menu to slide out. But this works really bad if using multiple device screens. Is there a wrap content kind of thing for this menu? Thanks